# Failure after tez shuffle handler setup : Map operator initialization failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

After Setup for the Tez Shuffle Handler following instructions on : https://tez.apache.org/shuffle-handler.html
I'm getting below error in query execution:

Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1608273679503_0002_2_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1608273679503_0002_2_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1608273679503_0002_2_01_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.daemon.impl.StatsRecordingThreadPool$WrappedCallable.call(StatsRecordingThreadPool.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:363)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:266)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Async Initialization failed. abortRequested=false
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:461)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:395)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:568)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:520)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:381)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:335)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.LlapObjectCache.retrieve(LlapObjectCache.java:118)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.LlapObjectCache$1.call(LlapObjectCache.java:143)
... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.mapjoin.fast.VectorMapJoinFastHashTableLoader.load(VectorMapJoinFastHashTableLoader.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTableInternal(MapJoinOperator.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:400)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.lambda$initializeOp$0(MapJoinOperator.java:207)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.LlapObjectCache.retrieve(LlapObjectCache.java:116)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tez.runtime.api.impl.TezTaskContextImpl.getServiceConsumerMetaData(TezTaskContextImpl.java:190)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.impl.ShuffleManager.(ShuffleManager.java:264)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.input.UnorderedKVInput.start(UnorderedKVInput.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.mapjoin.fast.VectorMapJoinFastHashTableLoader.load(VectorMapJoinFastHashTableLoader.java:109)
... 9 more

Can anyone help here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLAP internally uses MAP-REDUCE shuffle handler because inside TEZ code we have a hard-coded constant
TEZ_SHUFFLE_HANDLER_SERVICE_ID = "mapreduce_shuffle".
https://github.com/apache/tez/blob/master/tez-api/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/dag/api/TezConstants.java

So, when we are using tez_shuffle with LLAP its giving ‘NullpointerException’.